# how many ways to use Kotlin in android studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I have two android projects that use Kotlin. However, they have different ways to add Kotlin.

One seems to be used as a dependency(since it is in dependency block). The code below is located in Project level's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

The other seems to be used as plugin(since it is in plugins block). The code below is also located in Project level's build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "$hilt_version" apply false
}
```

I could find the first way to use Kotlin in [android developers](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#add) however, I can't find the second way to use Kotlin.

My question here is where to find these different ways to declare external source(I mean by dependency or plugins)? since I wasn't able to find it at Kotlin documentation.
(Or I will appreciate it if you could let me know some appropriate resources that talk about how android studio is structured and works overall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is the correct one today. The Kotlin plugin automatically adds the needed Kotlin library dependencies.

Note that you will need to have

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}
```

in the `build.gradle.kts` of modules (like `app`) that have Kotlin source, as well as the

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

in the root-level `build.gradle.kts`

See [Configure your build](https://developer.android.com/build) for details on the entire Android Gradle build setup.

Comment: do you also have some documentation that I could read about related to your answer? I will appreciate it if you could.

Comment: Added Android build page link to the answer.

Comment: Let me know if https://developer.android.com/build helps. I just made some edits to it, and wrote https://developer.android.com/build/jdks. If things are unclear I can see about making some changes.